# Can't find a way to save a table of data

Tags: lua, roblox, datastore

I have been working on a survival game base on "Booga Booga" but i cant seem to find out how to load player data on the game. The data im trying to load is saved in the for loop that follows:

```
module.SaveData = function (player, DT)
    local data_saved = {}
    
    local setData = player.inventory.Inv:GetChildren()
    for i, v in pairs(setData) do
        table.insert(data_saved, {[v] = {
            value = v.Value,
            name = v.Name
        }})
    end
    Data_Store:SetAsync(player.UserId, data_saved)
end
```

## **I've done multiple things to attempt to solve this problem**

1. I've tried load with http service
2. I've already attempted loading the raw table
3. and I've tried to use a global data store instead

here is my code that loads the data as of now:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    CF.PlayerInventorySetup(plr) -- not relavent
    p = plr -- not relavent
    local PD =require(game.ServerScriptService.DataHandler)
    local plrdata =PD.FetchData(plr)
    
    for i, v in pairs(plrdata) do -- this is what im having trouble with
        if not plr.inventory.Inv:FindFirstChild(v) then
            local newint = Instance.new("NumberValue")
            newint.Name = v.name -- the ouput says: string expected, got nil
            newint.Value = v.value -- 
            newint.Parent = plr.inventory.Inv
        end
    end
end)
```

I actually don't know wtf to do.

Comment: http service loading is a typo, i meant to say jsonencode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we talk about a solution, let's talk about what's happening when you save the data.  Let's say for example, your inventory is a list of NumberValues like this :

- Fish (value of 3)
- Iron (value of 10)
- Grass (value of 8)

Your `FetchData` function expects that the saved player data is formatted like this :

```
{
    { value =  3, name = "Fish"  },
    { value = 10, name = "Iron"  },
    { value =  8, name = "Grass" },
}
```

However, the result of the loop in the `SaveData` function would be this :

```
{
    { Fish(NumberValue) = { value=3, name="Fish" }},
    { Iron(NumberValue) = { value=10, name="Iron" }},
    { Grass(NumberValue) = { value=8, name="Grass" }},
}
```

On every step of the loop, you are pushing a new dictionary into the `data_saved` table.
The `FetchData` function expects that dictionary to have keys for "name" and "value". But, you've pushed that data one layer deeper, so those keys don't exist where the `FetchData` code expects them to and it throws errors.

So to fix your issue in the `SetData` function, remove the outer layer of that table, and just use the raw data.

```
table.insert(data_saved, {
    value = v.Value,
    name = v.Name
})
```